# Nature of stationary points of reciprocal functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

I have solved a problem but I'm not sure if the proof is right.

The problem is:
Show that if the curve $y=f(x)$ has a maximum stationary point at $x=a$ then the curve $y=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ has a minimum stationary point at $x=a$ where $f(a)\neq 0$

Here is what I've done:

I know that $f'(a)=0$ and $f''(a)<0$

and
$$\begin{equation}[\frac{1}{f(x)}]'' = -\frac{f(x)^2f''(x)-2f(x)f'(x)^2}{f(x)^4}\end{equation}$$
assuming $y=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ has a minimum stationary point at x=a then
$$\begin{equation}-\frac{f(a)^2f''(a)-2f(a)f'(a)^2}{f(a)^4}>0\end{equation}$$
which leads to
$$\begin{equation}f(a)^2f''(a)-2f(a)f'(a)^2<0\end{equation}$$
because $f'(a)=0$ we get
$$\begin{equation}f(a)^2f''(a)<0\end{equation}$$
because $f(a)\neq 0$ we get
$$\begin{equation}f''(a)<0\end{equation}$$
which is true and therefore $y=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ does have a minimum stationary point at $x=a$.

My question is why would this show that $y=\frac{1}{f(x)}$ does has a minimum stationary point at $x=a$ just because I assumed that it's true and deduced something true from it?

Comment: Actually you're not even given that $f''$ exists; in any case nothing here implies $f''(a)<0$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich The textbook this question is from is not that advanced so I think they just want you to assume that $f$ is twice differentiable

Comment: fine. But assuming $f$ is twice differentiable is not enough to get $f''(a)<0$.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Why would does this solution be correct?" says nothing about the subject of the question

Comment: Take $f(x)=1-x^4$. Then $f$ has a maximum at $x=0$, but $f''(0)=0$, not $<0$ as you claim

Comment: Changed the title. Should I have used epsilon-delta for this question? The level of this question is not supposed to be advanced.

Comment: I would be surprised if someone prove this without using epsilon/deltas

Answer (score 3):

This is false without some assumption on $f$:

> > **Example:** Let $f(0)=1$, $f(t)=-1$  for $t\ne0$. Then $f$ has a maximum at $a=0$ but $1/f$ does not have a minimum there.

But it's true if $f$ is just continuous. It seems sad to do something like this by calculus, when it's more or less obvious from what the words "maximum" and "minimum" *mean*:

> > **Lemma.** If $0<s<t$ or $s<t<0$ then $\frac1s>\frac1t$.

Now say $f$ is continuous, $f$ has a local maximum at $a$, and $f(a)\ne0$. Assume wlog $f(a)>0$. There exists $\delta>0$ such that (i) $f>0$ on all of $(a-\delta,a+\delta)=I$, (ii) $f(a)\ge f(t)$ for all $t\in I$. The lemma shows that $1/f(a)\le1/f(t)$ for all $t\in I$, so $1/f$ has a local minimum at$a$.

Comment: The existence of the first derivative ($a$ is a stationary point) gives us also continuity. A nice counterexample though.